# Twitter JSON to Google Spreadsheet API - 1. importing and reading JSON files

Tags: json, twitter, google-apps-script, google-sheets, trello

I'm trying to link Google Spreadsheet to twitter- have them talk to eachother - and I'm trying to use JSON.
(Trello and Google calendar are another idea with JSON)

from what I've gathered, you're supposed to use Utilities.JSONParse() for this data. I'm not sure what goes in the brackets to create a JSON object.  I keep getting an invalid JSON string when my basic code runs;

```
function myFunction() {
 var j = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.trello.com/1/organizations/fogcreek?key=727f13bf79cfa362db49b79eb8c56c94");
  Utilities.jsonParse(j);
}
```

So... examples/help on how to read JSON objects in a google spreadsheet would be great! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Google Docs spreadsheet a very clever guy has created which imports from Trello using Google Apps script:

http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/online-scrum-tools-part-4-trello-backup/

It takes the JSON data and translates it, so looking at his code may help you with twitter json import.

There's also another clever guy who explains how he's done something similar with Trello:

http://www.kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2012/03/05/project-progress-tracking-with-google-docs-and-trello/